# Chrome Extension to edit and/or create json file

Tags: json, file, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension that creates and/or edits JSON files that can be accessed by or stored into the users computer. I just want to know if this is possible and if it is how to go about doing it or some resource or guide I can look at. If its not possible is there another way I could extract information and store it locally on the computer. This is my first time building a chrome extension so I am not really sure what the chrome extension limits are. I have tried to find an answer but up to this point I have not found one. This is also my first time asking a question on stackoverflow so if you could me tips/suggestion to better clarify or format my question better in the future that would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading the chrome.fileSystem documentation and edit your question if something is not clear. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem